# Changing Tabbar color dynamically with ResourceDictionary

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Actually my app have 2 themes (pink and blue), handled by ResourceDictionary in App.xaml

Switching a switch in settings page change programmatically the values of the ResourceDictionary and the elements change as wanted (background, text colors etc).
It's maybe not the prettiest way but it works..

But i have a problem to change background colors of the Tabbar in android.

[image]

The color value of it is set in the Android project (colorPrimary from styles.xml and Tabbar.axml).

But i can't find

- How to change or access this value from my PCL project.
- Or how to change, in Android project, the value of that colorPrimary 
  each time the settings switch value is changed.
- Or also, the best solution, **make the tabbar transparent** and make it
  overlap the current background (if i set `Color.Transparent` it just
  become white now)

The tabbed page code is as been created by Xamarin forms project.

```
public MainPage()
        {
        Page centerPage, rightPage, leftPage;

        string TitleCenter = "S'exercer";
        string TitleLeft = "Comprendre";
        string TitleRight = "Aller plus loin";

        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                centerPage = new NavigationPage(new Center_Main())
                {
                    Title = TitleCenter
                };

                rightPage = new NavigationPage(new Right_Main())
                {
                    Title = TitleRight
                };
                leftPage = new NavigationPage(new Left_Main())
                {
                    Title = TitleLeft
                };
                centerPage.Icon = "tab_feed.png";
                rightPage.Icon = "tab_about.png";
                leftPage.Icon = "offline_logo.png";
                break;

            default:
                centerPage = new Center_Main()
                {
                    Title = TitleCenter
                    // Nothing tab related here
                };

                rightPage = new Right_Main()
                {
                    Title = TitleRight
                };

                leftPage = new Left_Main()
                {
                    Title = TitleLeft
                };

                break;
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Xaml it is something like this:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" BarBackgroundColor="your_Color"></Tabbedpage>
```

Programatically:

```
 TabbedPage page=new Tabbedpage(){ BarBackgroundColor=Color.Blue};
```

You can do the following in your tabbedPage constructor :

```
 public MainPage()
 {
    BarBackgroundColor=Color.Blue;
 }
```

**Note:** Can be used with static resources just put it in place of the color name.

Something like this

```
<... BarBackgroundColor={StaticResource color_name}>
```

Comment: I have no XAML with <TabbedPage.... , only in MainPage.cs i have public class MainPage : TabbedPage

Comment: Perfect that change the color of tabs. But what i need now is make this value dynamically changing with rest of theme. I tried 'public Color MainBarBackgroundColor { get; set; }' and 'BarBackgroundColor = MainBarBackgroundColor;' in MainPage.cs, but i still can't access to MainBarBackgroundColor from my setting page to change it's value at every switch

Comment: Can i see your implementation for changing colors ?

Comment: Working as wanted, i added OnApprearing on MainPage.cs and set the BarBackgroundColor according to my ResourceDictionary values. https://ibb.co/e1QBaH  Thanks for advices!

Comment: Great Goodluck i will update the code with your code soon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you go straight into the color that fills in the Tabbar this way:

xaml:

```
<ContentPage Title = "Menu" BackgroundColor = "{DynamicResource primary_colour}">
```

MainPage.

```
Application.Current.Resources ["primary_colour"] = Color.Green;
```

Comment: This will change the background color of all page, not the tabbar.

Comment: @Grounch in fact I put the background color of all page as an example, ideally you use this for the component you want to use, in this case, for your tabbar

Comment: Ah now i see what you wanted to show. But i was already using DynamicResources (with styles in app.xaml), the problem was to apply it to Tabbar

Comment: in this case the primary_colour could be of your tabbar, then you will be able to change its color. if it is solved thank you return: D

Comment: Yeah it's solved now look at the answer of G.Hakim ;)